# Is there a way to define a class as belonging inside a class from another file

Tags: java

Consider this example:

```java
//OuterClass.java

class OuterClass
{
  class InnerClass
  {
    Object parent()
    {
      return OuterClass.this;
    }
  }
}
```

Simple enough. InnerClass is created inside ("has an enclosing instance of") OuterClass, and has access to it.

Now, my problem is that in my case, OuterClass is **BIG**, and has multiple "inner classes".
As such, I would like to try to split all of this into multiple files.

Is there a way to tell a class that it "belongs into" another class?
Something in the likes of:

```java
//OuterClass.java

class OuterClass
{
  class InnerClass definedIn InnerClass.java;
}
```

```java
//InnerClass.java

class InnerClass needsEnclosingInstanceOf OuterClass
{
  Object parent()
  {
    return OuterClass.this;
  }
}
```

or is the only way really just to make a constructor that needs an instance of the class, and access the class through that object?

Comment: no, not really. but having inner classes is an exception to the rule, per-se; they are rarely really needed. I would start looking into that, first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A class and its inner classes *must* be in the same Java source file.  There is no good way around this.

I guess you could feed your source code through some kind of pre-processor to assemble the real Java source file from a bunch of component files.  But that will raise a bunch of other problems<sup>1</sup>.  So is it (IMO) not something that is worth pursuing.

My advice: either put up with the unpleasantly large source file, or split it into separate classes in separate files.

---

Note that inner classes are actually a form of syntactic sugar.  At the implementation level, the inner classes' constructor is passed a hidden extra parameter which is a reference to an instance of the outer class.  You can do the same thing explicitly to get equivalent behavior without class nesting.

---

<sup>1 - For instance, it will break your IDE ... unless the IDE understands the syntax and semantics of the hypothetical preprocessor.</sup>

Comment: Riiiiight, it's that "this$0" I keep seeing in the debugger, isn't it...